# Docker+Airflow+Nginx reverse proxy doesn't work

Tags: docker, nginx, airflow

I'm trying to build my system as below and all components are builded by docker.

- nginx -> index.html(localhost:8080)
- nginx -> airflow(localhost:8080/airflow/)
- nginx -> flower(localhost:8080/flower/)

"http://localhost:8080" is worked and show index.html about nginx,
but when I type into "http://localhost:8080/airflow/" doesn't work and log output was like below. How can I fix this issue?

> nginx-for-airflow_1  | 2022/08/04 09:09:42 [error] 30#30: *5 "/usr/share/nginx/html/airflow/index.html" is not found

and my code like below

- nginx.conf

  ```
    upstream airflow_webserver {
        server airflow-webserver:8080;
    }

    upstream airflow_flower {
        server flower:5555;
    }

    server {
        root /;

        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;
        charset utf-8;

        # location ^~ / {
        #     deny all;
        # }

        location /airflow/ {
            proxy_pass              http://airflow_webserver;
            proxy_redirect          off;
            proxy_http_version      1.1;
            proxy_set_header        Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header        Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
        }

        location /flower/ {
            proxy_pass              http://airflow_flower/;
            proxy_redirect          off;
            proxy_http_version      1.1;
            proxy_set_header        Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header        Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
        }
    }
  ```
- and I modified my airflow.cfg like below

```
base_url = http://airflow-webserver:8080
web_server_port = 8080
enable_proxy_fix = True
proxy_fix_x_port = 3
```

- my docker-compose.yaml file, and I checked I can access flower url in "airflow-webserver" container using "curl http://flower:5555"

```yaml
    nginx-for-airflow:
        image: nginx:latest
        volumes:
          - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
        ports:
          - 8080:80
        healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/"]
          interval: 10s
          timeout: 10s
          retries: 5
        restart: always
        depends_on:
          <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
          airflow-init:
            condition: service_completed_successfully
          flower:
            condition: service_healthy
          airflow-webserver:
            condition: service_healthy
    
    flower:
        <<: *airflow-common
        command: celery flower
        # profiles:
        #   - flower
        # ports:
        #   - 5555:5555
        expose:
          - 5555
        healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:5555/"]
          interval: 10s
          timeout: 10s
          retries: 5
        restart: always
        depends_on:
          <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
          airflow-init:
            condition: service_completed_successfully
    
    airflow-webserver:
        <<: *airflow-common
        command: webserver
        expose:
          - 8080
        healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/health"]
          interval: 10s
          timeout: 10s
          retries: 5
        restart: always
        depends_on:
          <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
          airflow-init:
            condition: service_completed_successfully
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the `root` directive into a `location / {}`  block. All requests are matching the server-level root.

Comment: you mean like below?
```
server {
    location / {
       ...
    }
```

Comment: I'm add the code below the server section, but it's occurred same issue

`
location / {
            root /;
        }
`